# What is the noun to describe the possible responses to the question "How did you hear about us?"

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns

I am modelling the allowed responses for the question "How did you hear about us?" in a CRM (Customer Relationship Management) system. How would you name this type of entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some examples could be

- Reference
- Referrer/referral
- Lead

Comment: Thank you, we are going to use Referral to distinguish from the technical referrer in HTTP.